# Encoding of dynamically-generated HTML markup

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, unicode, codepages

On the right is a jQuery UI sortable list, on the left there's another sortable list. As you can see, on the left column my language is supported (one with black circle).

Although this one is a hard-coded list item, and the rest of the (SilverPlated) list items is HTML markup (dynamically) generated from C# code.

This is the first time I encountered this problem after publishing my application to the server. This server is not in my country and also it is my first time with this server, so I guess something is causing the code to be generated in a different localization/encoding.

Question:

Is it the duty of my hosting service, tech support department, etc to make some changes in my hosting plan or do I need to set it myself in my C# code?

As it is done within a for loop length of collection do:  `string.Format("<li id={0}_{1}></li>",variableId, counter)`;

When on a local (VisualStudio) server, it's fine... Always was.

[image]

Comment: It's your code. Make sure you use the proper encoding (ideally UTF8) in the Page directive and the HTML Head tag. Also make sure you save your aspx files as UTF8 instead of ANSI. Finally, ensure that any stored data is either in Unicode format (eg nvarchar database fields) or that you specify the proper locale/language when loading the data.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Encoding on your web.config to utf-8, as

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

because probably the server have a different one than yours, so by adding that you have the same on both computers and you solve it.

Comment: @AviaAfer Or maybe not on utf-8 but in your country encode - see your global settings on `c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config` or similar folder

Comment: the only thing i could find that is to do with that setting in local config as in your comment is - *Culture=neutral* (Ctrl +F on "glob" yeald - no results , and adding one in your answer to online web.config within the System.web caused an error 501 i might have placed it in wrong place